# CSS: Center Image on top of div that acts as Background

Tags: html, css

I don't know why this image won't center. I need it to be centered at the exact center and this should work if screen is resized (I'm using bootstrap 4).

**html:**

```
<div id="general-container" class="general-container preloader">

        <img src="">
</div>
```

**css:**

```
    .preloader {

    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    transition: 1s;
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: .8;
}

#general-container {
    background-image: url("/static/img/logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: absolute;

}
```

[image]

Project Structure:

```
-llama-stickers
 |_cart
   |_templates
     |_cart.html
 |_llama-stickers
 |_order
 |_search_app
 |_shop
   |_templates
     |_base.html
 |_static
   |_css
     |_preloader.css
   |_img
     |_logo.png
```

Comment: The general container should be full width and height, and use background position center..

Comment: firstly, you shouldn't have an ID and a class that both use the same name. Especially on the same element. That's not proper and is asking for trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took out the `.general-container` class as it appeared you did not need it. Also, you shouldn't have classes with identical names as IDs. Please try the following code:

```css
.preloader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
    transition: 1s;
    z-index: 9999;
    opacity: .8;
}

#general-container {
    background: #000 url("https://arviem.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/logo.ico") center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="general-container" class="preloader"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want this centered vertically and horizontally, give this a try - https://jsfiddle.net/4c6n9bjq/1/

Made a few code changes and use a stock image for the sake of example

**HTML**

```
<div id="general-container" class="preloader">
   <div class="photo-bg">


   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .preloader {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 100vh;
   background: #000;
   transition: 1s;
   opacity: .8;
 }

 .photo-bg {
   background-image: url("http://people.cs.ksu.edu/~xou/argus/img/profile/placeholder.png");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   display: block;
   width: 250px;
   height: 250px;
   top: 40vh;
   left: 40vw;
   position: absolute;
 }
```

The key thing being that you assign the necessary vh and vw values to your image div based on the image dimensions. Once you get those right the image will scale appropriately across screen sizes.

Comment: The select answer is the cleanest and easiest code :(